# Prove: $x \in \bar{B} \iff V \cap B \neq \emptyset \forall V \in Nbh(x)$

Tags: general-topology

I want to prove that $x \in \bar{B} \iff V \cap B \neq \emptyset$ $\forall$ $V \in Nbh(x)$ where $\bar{B}$ is the closure of B.

I have a proof by contrapositive in mind:

$x \not \in \bar{B} \iff \exists V \in Nbh(x):  V \cap B = \emptyset$.

$\Rightarrow$ Take an $x \in X$ and assume $x \not \in \bar{B}$. Then $x \in X \backslash \bar{B}$. As $\bar{B}$ is closed, $X\backslash \bar{B}$ is open. As $X \backslash \bar{B}$ is open there exists a neighbourhood $V \in Nbh(x)$ such that $ V \cap \bar{B} = \emptyset$. As $B \subseteq \bar{B}$ then $V \cap B = \emptyset$ also holds.

$\Leftarrow$ Assume there exists a $ V \in Nbh(x):  V \cap B = \emptyset$.  As $V$ is open, $X\backslash V$ is closed. Take an $x \in V$. Since $\bar{B}$ is the smallest possible closed set such that $B \subseteq \bar{B}$ then $\bar{B} \subseteq X\backslash V$. As $B \subseteq \bar{B} \subseteq X\backslash V$ and $x \in V$ then $x \not \in \bar{B}$.

Is this proof complete? I am fairly new to proof writing so any tips on how to improve this proof, or proof writing in general, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are two typos. In the first part you wrote $B \subseteq V$ instead of $B \subseteq \overline {B}$. In the converse part you ended the proof with $x \notin B$ instead of $x \notin \overline {B}$.

Comment: Ah you're absolutely right. I have updated the answer now. Thanks for spotting those.

Comment: It is correct and fine, yet you should remove the useless sentence "Take an $x \in V$." in the proof of $\Leftarrow$.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @OlivierRoche

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof idea is fine, but could be written down more accurately, maybe like this:

Let $x \notin \overline{B}$, then $V=X\setminus \overline{B}$ is open and contains $x$ and $B \subseteq \overline{B}$ implies $V \subseteq X\setminus B$ and clearly then $V \cap B=\emptyset$, so the right hand side of the equivalence (in negated form) has been shown.

Reversely, if $x$ is such that it has an open neighbourhood $V$ disjoint from $B$ then $B \subseteq X\setminus V$, which is closed, and as $\overline{B}$ is the *smallest* closed set containing $B$, $\overline{B} \subseteq X\setminus V$ or equivalently $\overline{B} \cap V=\emptyset$ and in particular, $x \notin \overline{B}$.

Comment: Thanks Henno! :)